# create date object from 2 columns

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have 2 columns:

```
dt_year, dt_month
2014     3
```

I need a date column.

I tried something like:

```
pd.to_datetime((df.dt_year + df.dt_month +1).apply(str),format='%Y%m%d')
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: time data '2014' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, change the column names to something more normal.  then add a `'day'` column.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('dt_', '')
df['day'] = 1

df

   year  month  day
0  2014      3    1
```

Then the magic happens

```
pd.to_datetime(df)

0   2014-03-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could do that... Thanks for the solution!